# How many times each value from a list appears in a column in another table. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table of id values and need to count how many times each of those ids appears in a column in another table.

I have figured out how to do it only for values that appear at least once:

```
SELECT one.id, COUNT(*) FROM table1 one, table2 two WHERE one.id = two.id GROUP BY one.id;
```

but can't figure out how to also include ids that appear in first but don't appear in second table at all.

Example:

```
table1:       table2:

+-----+      +-----+
| id  |      | id  |
+-----+      +-----+
| 11  |      | 11  |
| 12  |      | 12  |
| 13  |      | 14  |
| 14  |      | 11  |
+-----+      | 11  |
             | 12  |
             +-----+
```

The result would be:

```
+-----+----------+
| id  | count(*) |
+-----+----------+
| 11  | 3        |
| 12  | 2        |
| 14  | 1        |
+-----+----------+
```

I'm trying to make it also include line `| 13  | 0    |`

Comment: Instead of implicit `INNER JOIN` use explicit `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an implicit inner join which is discouraged. Instead what you need is a left join, something like:

```
SELECT one.id, COUNT(two.id) 
FROM table1 one LEFT JOIN table2 two 
ON one.id = two.id 
GROUP BY one.id;
```

Comment: Now it does include the 13 but has 1 in it's count column instead of 0. How can we fix that?

Comment: Have modified the answer, so it uses two.id which if null then wont add to count.